# java Error while connecting oracle datasource from Jboss 6.3 server

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, jboss6.x

> 22:25:32,256 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TestDatasource].[jsp]]
>   (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   jsp threw exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env --
>   service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.env    at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:103)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:241)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown
>   Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]     at
>   com.java.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:27) [classes:]
>     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:66)

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>java:jboss/datasources/<datasource name></res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/<datasource name>"     pool-name="<pool name>" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:<port>:DB</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>oracleDS</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name><user></user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
</datasource>

<driver name="oracleDS" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

**Module.xml**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

**DBConnection.java**

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/TAXLOT_JNDI_DATASOURCE");
Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Getting folllowing error 
JBWEB000068: message javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env -- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.env

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env -- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.env
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:848)

Comment: We would need a lot more of your code to identify the real problem. Like where is you look up code executed from. Have a look at the joss documentation on name spaces.  The java:comp name space just means the name space of the current component so getting a lookup failing at the level of java:comp/env would indicate that there is no current component. I notice that the error message only says comp/env does this indicate that the error is caused by a different resource request? Also if this is joss eap 6.3 , why are you not injecting your resources?